# Does APNs provider API requirement starts March 31 notice applicable to Appcelerator Mobile Backend Services

Tags: ios, push-notification, titanium, appcelerator, apn

We use PHP backend to connect to appcelerator notification REST API. In this scenario does APNs provider API requirement starts March 31 notice applicable to Appcelerator Mobile Backend Services

Answer (score 0):

Check out the post at: https://devblog.axway.com/featured/product-update-changes-to-application-development-services-appcelerator/

It says `September 1, 2022: End of Support – Mobile Backend Services`.

So make sure to transfer to a different push provider e.g. to Firebase (https://github.com/hansemannn/titanium-firebase-cloud-messaging) before that date.

The Titanium SDK is open source so you still can use that after that time

Comment: Thanks for the update. And for the original question do we need to do anything for the apn provider api requirement which is to be fullfilled by 31st March

Comment: are you talking about the Apple mail for the APN stuff at the 29th of March this year? That is something that appc needed to implement and I'm sure it is already there

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your time and help